# `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph` not showing the "--graph" part in CLI?

Tags: git

I need a simple way to quickly check a branch and commit three.
So I went to the Git documentation and found [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
```

Output:

```
* 2d3acf9 Ignore errors from SIGCHLD on trap
*  5e3ee11 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/dustin/grit.git
|\
| * 420eac9 Add method for getting the current branch
* | 30e367c Timeout code and tests
* | 5a09431 Add timeout protection to grit
* | e1193f8 Support for heads with slashes in them
|/
* d6016bc Require time for xmlschema
*  11d191e Merge branch 'defunkt' into local
```

However the actual output in CLI looks like this

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph
```

Output:

```
* 2d3acf9 Ignore errors from SIGCHLD on trap
*  5e3ee11 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/dustin/grit.git
* 420eac9 Add method for getting the current branch
* 30e367c Timeout code and tests
* 5a09431 Add timeout protection to grit
* e1193f8 Support for heads with slashes in them
* d6016bc Require time for xmlschema
* 11d191e Merge branch 'defunkt' into local
```

I can achieve what I need by using this command:

`git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all`

But as you can see, it's too long and easy to type when in a rush.
I can't always use an alias to shorten it.

What is wrong with `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph`?

I need to run this mainly on Windows in [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell), but also on Linux in terminal.

What didn't help me:

- *[Git graph not showing branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217363/git-graph-not-showing-branch)*. This is fixed by changing the way how the user works with commits.  Not helpful.
- *[How to read a Git log graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382255/how-to-read-git-log-graph)*. This simply explains how to read the `--graph` output.

Comment: can you describe your cli context ? OS, shell (and possibly terminal), if it is a plain local shell (e.g: `bash` on your local linux system, or `cmd.exe` on Windows, or a ssh console, or ...)

Comment: fwiw: I know I have the expected output on bash/Ubuntu, cmd.exe/Windows 10 and powershell/Windows 10. Something is meddling with your output.

Comment: @LeGEC Hey there, as i mentioned in the question , it's 
"I need to run this mainly on Windows in PowerShell but also on Linux in terminal." 
To be more precise Win 10, Win 11 powershell 1.0 and 7.0 also Linux FXCE terminal, google cloud console ssh in browser for start but I would like it to work regardless of system.

Comment: @LeGEC  
I managed to make it work by adding `--all` at the end of the command.   
Apparently it doesn't work other way in certain cases.

Comment: "in linux on terminal" : do you see the same glitch when running that command on linux ?

Comment: @LeGEC interesting.   It's not Linux vs Windows or cmd vs ps vs linux terminal issue.  
It's project specific. Some projects do that while other don't. I just tested on those that do at first. Do you know what makes that happened.  `--all` fixes it by showing entire history of repo.

Comment: What do you mean by *"commit three"*? *"commit [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command))"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log --oneline --all --graph --reflog` is what I use for this purpose.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input.  Solution i found before you answered was to add `--all`  into the command.  
Your answer is basically doing the same.
Reason you got down-voted by someone (not me) was most likely because you didn't add explanation.    
I can edit your answer but it's better to let you know.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to graphically represent the complete commit tree in CLI by adding `--all` into the command.

#### Fast way

`git log --oneline --graph --all`

#### Simple but customizable way with `--pretty=format`

`git log --pretty=format:"%h %ar %s" --graph --all`

| code | desc |
| --- | --- |
| `git log` | commit history |
| `--pretty=format:"%h %s"` | shown data |
| `--graph` | ASCII art-based visualization of branches |
| `--all` | displays entire commit history from all branches |

part inside `--pretty=format:"%h %ar %s"` allows to customize printed data.

[GIT doc example](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats):
E.g, format:"The author of %h was %an, %ar%nThe title was >>%s<<%n" would show something like this:

```
The author of fe6e0ee was Junio C Hamano, 23 hours ago
The title was >>t4119: test autocomputing -p<n> for traditional diff input.
```

Comment: fwiw : `git log --oneline --graph` . `--oneline` is basically a shortcut for `--pretty="%h %s"`, which should autocomplete.

Comment: Well yes, `- - oneline`  is shortcut for `<hash> <title-line> `   however using pretty allows for additional customization.

Comment: What do you mean by *"commit three"*? *"commit [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(command))"*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen  Typo indeed.  I meant tree like structure of commits portrayed in graphical way. Purpose is to show how each branch grows, merge points and each commits with additional details.